# How to branch recursion into returning only a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, nested-lists

I'm having a problem where I what I need returning should be a list of lists, with each nested list being a list of 2 strings. I can't find a way to flatten this list effectively, or to return just the list of lists, as the number of nested lists is undeterminable. This is happening in my recursive function, where I branch into 3 different paths of recursion for each recursive loop.
What I have so far is:

```
def f(used, sequences):
    if sequences[0] == '' or sequences[1] == '':
        if sequences[0] == '' and sequences[1] == '':
            return [used[0], used[1]]
        elif sequences[0] != '':
            return [used[0] + sequences[0], used[1] + '-' * len(sequences[0])]
        elif sequences[1] != '':
            return [used[0] + '-' * len(sequences[1]), used[1] + sequences[1]]
    else:
        return [f([sequences[0][-1] + used[0], sequences[1][-1] + used[1]], [sequences[0][:-1], sequences[1][:-1]]),
        f([sequences[0][-1] + used[0], '-' + used[1]], [sequences[0][:-1], sequences[1]]),
        f(['-' + used[0], sequences[1][-1] + used[1]], [sequences[0], sequences[1][:-1]])]
```

What I want is for alignments to be every possible alignment of the 2 sequences paired up. However, it produces a complex series of nested loops which is undeterminable due to the possible different lengths of the sequences. Using the above function as such produces:

```
sequences = ['GAA', 'TGT']
alignments = f(['', ''], sequences)
print(alignments)
>>>[[[['GAA', 'TGT'], ['GAA-', '-GTT'], ['-AAG', 'TGT-']], [['GAA-', 'G-TT'], ['GAA--', '--TTG'], [['G-AA', 'TG-T'], ['G-AA-', '-G-TT'], ['--AAG', 'TG-T-']]], [['A-AG', 'TGT-'], [['GA-A', 'T-GT'], ['GA-A-', '--GTT'], ['-A-AG', 'T-GT-']], ['--AGA', 'TGT--']]], [[['GAA-', 'GT-T'], ['GAA--', '-T-TG'], [['G-AA', 'TGT-'], ['G-AA-', '-GT-T'], ['--AAG', 'TGT--']]], [['GAA--', 'T--TG'], ['GAA---', '---TGT'], [['G-AA-', 'GT--T'], ['G-AA--', '-T--TG'], [['G--AA', 'TGT--'], ['G--AA-', '-GT--T'], ['---AAG', 'TGT---']]]], [[['GA-A', 'TGT-'], ['GA-A-', '-GT-T'], ['-A-AG', 'TGT--']], [['GA-A-', 'G-T-T'], ['GA-A--', '--T-TG'], [['G-A-A', 'TG-T-'], ['G-A-A-', '-G-T-T'], ['--A-AG', 'TG-T--']]], [['A--AG', 'TGT--'], [['GA--A', 'T-GT-'], ['GA--A-', '--GT-T'], ['-A--AG', 'T-GT--']], ['---AGA', 'TGT---']]]], [[['AA-G', 'TGT-'], [['GAA-', 'T-GT'], ['GAA--', '--GTT'], ['-AA-G', 'T-GT-']], ['-A-GA', 'TGT--']], [[['GAA-', 'TG-T'], ['GAA--', '-G-TT'], ['-AA-G', 'TG-T-']], [['GAA--', 'G--TT'], ['GAA---', '---TTG'], [['G-AA-', 'TG--T'], ['G-AA--', '-G--TT'], ['--AA-G', 'TG--T-']]], [['A-A-G', 'TG-T-'], [['GA-A-', 'T-G-T'], ['GA-A--', '--G-TT'], ['-A-A-G', 'T-G-T-']], ['--A-GA', 'TG-T--']]], [['A--GA', 'TGT--'], [['AA--G', 'T-GT-'], [['GAA--', 'T--GT'], ['GAA---', '---GTT'], ['-AA--G', 'T--GT-']], ['-A--GA', 'T-GT--']], ['---GAA', 'TGT---']]]]
```

which will generate something like `[[[['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str']], [['str, 'str']...` when I want it to come out as `[['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str']...`
Is there a way to fix my recursion so that this is the case, or a function I can write to flatten it the way I want?

Having tried Ch3steR's recommendation of:

```
def flat(lst):
     if not isinstance(lst[0][0],list):
         return lst
     else:
        return flat(sum(lst,[]))
```

I am a lot closer to what I want. However, there are still some nested loops within.

```
sequences = ['GAA', 'TGT']
alignments = f(['', ''], sequences)
alignments = flat(alignments)
print(alignments)
```

Now produces:

```
[['GAA', 'TGT'], ['GAA-', '-GTT'], ['-AAG', 'TGT-'], ['GAA-', 'G-TT'], ['GAA--', '--TTG'], [['G-AA', 'TG-T'], ['G-AA-', '-G-TT'], ['--AAG', 'TG-T-']], ['A-AG', 'TGT-'], [['GA-A', 'T-GT'], ['GA-A-', '--GTT'], ['-A-AG', 'T-GT-']], ['--AGA', 'TGT--'], ['GAA-', 'GT-T'], ['GAA--', '-T-TG'], [['G-AA', 'TGT-'], ['G-AA-', '-GT-T'], ['--AAG', 'TGT--']], ['GAA--', 'T--TG'], ['GAA---', '---TGT'], [['G-AA-', 'GT--T'], ['G-AA--', '-T--TG'], [['G--AA', 'TGT--'], ['G--AA-', '-GT--T'], ['---AAG', 'TGT---']]], [['GA-A', 'TGT-'], ['GA-A-', '-GT-T'], ['-A-AG', 'TGT--']], [['GA-A-', 'G-T-T'], ['GA-A--', '--T-TG'], [['G-A-A', 'TG-T-'], ['G-A-A-', '-G-T-T'], ['--A-AG', 'TG-T--']]], [['A--AG', 'TGT--'], [['GA--A', 'T-GT-'], ['GA--A-', '--GT-T'], ['-A--AG', 'T-GT--']], ['---AGA', 'TGT---']], ['AA-G', 'TGT-'], [['GAA-', 'T-GT'], ['GAA--', '--GTT'], ['-AA-G', 'T-GT-']], ['-A-GA', 'TGT--'], [['GAA-', 'TG-T'], ['GAA--', '-G-TT'], ['-AA-G', 'TG-T-']], [['GAA--', 'G--TT'], ['GAA---', '---TTG'], [['G-AA-', 'TG--T'], ['G-AA--', '-G--TT'], ['--AA-G', 'TG--T-']]], [['A-A-G', 'TG-T-'], [['GA-A-', 'T-G-T'], ['GA-A--', '--G-TT'], ['-A-A-G', 'T-G-T-']], ['--A-GA', 'TG-T--']], ['A--GA', 'TGT--'], [['AA--G', 'T-GT-'], [['GAA--', 'T--GT'], ['GAA---', '---GTT'], ['-AA--G', 'T--GT-']], ['-A--GA', 'T-GT--']], ['---GAA', 'TGT---']]
```

Comment: What is the value for the parameters? Please [edit] your question and that data and a [mre]

Comment: Please elaborate on how your nested list looks like.

Comment: @OcasoProtal Apologies for being vague initially. I have updated the question to show the inputs and outputs I have used and received

Comment: @Jameseph check the edited answer I posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood I posted this answer.

You use `sum` to reduce 1dim of a nested list.

```
def flat(lst):
     if not isinstance(lst[0][0],list):
         return lst
     else:
        return flat(sum(lst,[]))

a=[[[['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str']], [['str', 'str']]]]
flat(a)
#[['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str'], ['str', 'str']]
```

---

EDIT:
For arbitrarily nested list.

```
def flat(lst,curr=[]):
    if len(lst)==2 and all(isinstance(i,str) for i in lst):
        return [lst]
    else:
        for i in lst:
            curr=curr+flat(i)
    return curr
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to an extent, but still occasionally produces nested lists that I do not want. For example, when run with the sequences 'GAA' and 'TGT', `...['GAA--', '--TTG'], [['G-AA', 'TG-T'], ['G-AA-', '-G-TT'], ['--AAG', 'TG-T-']], ['A-AG', 'TGT-']...` occurs.

Comment: @Jameseph check the edited answer. It should work now.